# Create a raw transaction

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

How could i create a 0 fee bitcoin transaction ? I tried to create a manual transaction, using online services ,but get an error while broadcasting.Also i tried to create this transaction using bicore library and node.js , but without rezults

Comment: most nodes will not accept a zero fee transaction, the problem isn't how do you create it, the problem is who can you send it to that will mine it (miners don't usually work for free).

Comment: This question appears to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as the over-arching questions isn't about programming, but rather about Bitcoin. You would find better answers asking this question on a more appropriate site such as the [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) website.

Comment: @JBaczuk , I do not need this transaction to be confirmed . Can i run my own bitcoin node and accept this 0 fee transaction ? I need her to remain unconfirmed

Comment: @Cristyan yes, but you have to modify the validation rules, and you also have to modify the code where by default it will throw out unconfirmed transactions after two weeks.

Answer (score -1):

When you make a raw transaction you specify inputs and outputs, for example:

If you have only **1 input** with 10 BTC and **1 output** with 7 BTC (the output could be someones address) the **fee will be 3 BTC**.

To make a 0 fee transaction the **input** BTC number should be the same as **output** (**10 - 10 = 0**).

If you try to broadcast a 0 fee transaction it will throw an error like "Too low fee, set a higher fee".